# Pre-convert figures into a specific format?

Tags: graphics, pdf, svg, png, jpeg

I have a set of figures with different formats: `jpg`, `png`, `svg`, `pdf`. Most figures are produced by me (plots) so I have a choice as to the format in which to save them in. I'm not sure if I should pre-convert all figures to a particular format as a one-off. I use `luatex`. I am unsure about these things:

1. Does latex convert figures when compiling? If so, considering most
   figures never change, can I do this conversion manually as a one off
   and store it so that latex can easily embed the figures when putting
   the document together.
2. I find it unnecessary to have more than 1 figure format. Can I
   convert to a universal format and which one would be best. I'll do
   this as a one-off.

Comment: latexmk can do such thing, but I don't sure if latexmk can be used with luatex

Comment: I don't particularly care if I use luatex or anything else. I picked luatex as it seemed more modern but I can swap it.

Comment: See the documentation of latexmk in page 46, you can have a try.

Comment: Just for avoidance of doubt and future readers, you mean this: http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf

Comment: Yes, you may also get it by `texdoc latexmk`

Comment: (1) LaTeX accept JPG and PNG images, but for plots for LaTeX never save due to the loss of quality (2) You can use vectorial plots saved as EPS (now exported automatically to PDF) and SVG (using svg package to export it to PDF with inkscape), but (3) the simplest and better is use directly PDF plots, so they can be used by `graphicx` without exports at compilation times. Of course, by "PDF plots" I mean  saved as true vectorial plots, editables with Inkscape, not as a  jpg/png embedded in a PDF (i.e., unlike a photography in a PDF).

Comment: If you are using pdflatex, then the image will be stored in its entirety, without cropping or loss of resolution.  (It's a PDF thing.)